# What is the unit of content-length for postman?

Tags: postman

I'm started using postman recently, I can see response of my content like this 
[image]

Where as when I save the response into a file on my local system it looks like this

[image]

I can see from locally that file size is ~10KB where as the same response on postman show it as ~6.61KB, in what sense is this huge difference possible?

### EDIT

The number given by postman doesn't match with no.of characters in the file.

> C02SH03Q:~ pvangala$ wc test/2.txt
>
> 256     523    9690 test/2.txt

Comment: network compression?

Comment: @jean would that be possible? as I'm running this app locally?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to auto formatting of raw text to JSON content, as a result the size of the content increases.